# how to save entry in table in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I'm creating a simple demo using this link 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro .
I am able to get click event **(Please click on first column edit image)**. It shows a modal. I open a modal on click of image. It show **pre-filled** entries of selected item. I also able to get click buttons **(save and cancel)** present in model, but I want this: if a user changes the **first and second** present in input field, it reflects in table when the user presses **save** button.

Here is my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PLy6rSUIOMoVO6iKfPOY?p=preview

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, row, grid) {

  var vm=this;
  console.log(row);
  vm.first=row.entity.name;
  vm.second=row.entity.lastname;

  vm.save = function () {
    alert('save')
  };

  vm.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
  vm.save = function () {
    row.entity.name = vm.first
    row.entity.lastname = vm.second
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
```

As you still have reference and that each controller seem to be created with its own row, then you can simply save the data back into the `row.entity` object. As simple as that.